# gitlab pipeline: get hostname inside gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, gitlab, ip, gitlab-ci

I run several docker commands in `gitlab-ci.yml`.
Some of them require current machine IP address to be passed to them, like this:

```
docker build --pull -t my_image . --add-host=<my service>:<current ip>
```

`$CI_SERVER_HOSTNAME` is not the one, its value is `gitlab.com`. I need actual IP address of the CI machine as `ifconfig` would see it from `.gitlab-cy.yml` file.

I am not finding any $CI_... variable for that. I know extraction from ifconfig is possible, but won't work when the docker commands executed one-by-one on Mac.

Note: I know it's usually something like 172.0.0.x, but need an exact one plus I wonder if the variable for it exists.

Comment: Hi, there is no predifned variable for the gitlab runner: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html instead of ifconfig you can also just make a call to a service for getting the public ip. Might be less scripting than ifconfig

Comment: @ghovat Thank you. At the end I redesigned the system so instead the stuff I needed current machine IP for is running in another container. So, I get that container IP address abd pas it as an env variable to my container.  Works

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the ip address of the machine that the runner is executed.

We will use the Gitlab API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#get-runners-details

```
GET /runners/:id
```

This API call will return the details of the runner with this specific **:id**. When a job executes this id is available on **CI_RUNNER_ID** predefined variable.

By combining all this and utilizing `jq` and `sed`

 
We get the following one liner that returns the ip address of the runner that is executing the current job

```
curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your access token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners/${CI_RUNNER_ID}  | jq '.ip_address' | sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/'
```

Comment: Thank you Tolis, since the question was posted then I have changed jobs twice so I can not try your solution  it anymore.